# Select from different tables in Query By Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, lambda

I need to select Data from different tables. I don't want to repeat the same codes once for each table. Is there a solution?
Previously, the table name could be specified as a variable in SQL commands. It is a bit dangerous in terms of security, but I need this item.

If it is not possible, how can I run the SQL commands directly in ASP.NET Core

```cs
string tblname="users";
```

```sql
select * from {tblname};
```

select Data from different tables or run the SQL commands directly in ASP.NET Core

for Example in this code I want `blogs` name is variable

```cs
var retdata= context.blogs.FromSql("SELECT * From Blogs").ToList();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the language you're coding in. Also, please explain what you have found when you researched this issue and why those solutions aren't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with dictionary or datatable.

> 1. In your dbcontext file

```
public class LinqTest2Context : DbContext
{
    public LinqTest2Context (DbContextOptions<LinqTest2Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<LinqTest2.Models.User> User { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<LinqTest2.Models.Inf> Inf { get; set; } = default!;

    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetJoinedTableDataAsList(
        string tableA, string tableB,
        string tableAColumn, string tableBColumn,
        IEnumerable<string> columnNames)
    {
        // Validate the table and column name to prevent SQL injection
        var tableNames = this.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(t => t.GetTableName()).ToList();
        if (!tableNames.Contains(tableA) || !tableNames.Contains(tableB))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid table name.");
        }

        var allowedColumnNamesA = this.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetTableName() == tableA)?
            .GetProperties().Select(p => p.GetColumnName()).ToList();

        var allowedColumnNamesB = this.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetTableName() == tableB)?
            .GetProperties().Select(p => p.GetColumnName()).ToList();

        var selectedColumns = columnNames.Where(c => allowedColumnNamesA.Contains(c) || allowedColumnNamesB.Contains(c)).ToList();
        if (!selectedColumns.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid or no column names provided.");
        }

        //Verify column names of table
        var columnList = string.Join(", ", selectedColumns.Select(c => $"{(allowedColumnNamesA.Contains(c) ? "A" : "B")}.[{c}]"));
        var resultList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var sql = $"SELECT {columnList} FROM [{tableA}] A JOIN [{tableB}] B ON A.[{tableAColumn}] = B.[{tableBColumn}]";

        var command = Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        Database.OpenConnection();

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(reader);
        resultList = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                dict[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
            }
            return dict;
        }).ToList();

        return resultList;
    }
}
```

> 2. In your method it can be called this way

```
var tableA = "User";
var tableB = "Inf";
var tableAColumn = "InfId";
var tableBColumn = "InfNum";
var columns = new List<string> { "InfName", "UserName" };
var data = _context.GetJoinedTableDataAsList(tableA, tableB, tableAColumn, tableBColumn, columns);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1. Option One:** You can use a stored procedure with a parameter `@tableName`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DataFromTable
    @TableName NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery;
END
```

And in ASP.NET Core, you can call this stored procedure using Entity Framework Core:

```
string tableName = "users";
var retdata = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntity>("usp_DataFromTable @p0", tableName).ToList();
```

**2. Option Two:** Use dynamic SQL directly in ASP.NET Core, by using the `FromSqlRaw` method.

```
string tableName = "users";
string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}";
var data = context.MyEntities.FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery}").ToList();
```